# Gilbert Strang Linear Algebra: Solve Differential Eqn Back Sub - 6.3 Q2

Tags: linear-algebra

Given:

d**u**/dt = \begin{bmatrix}4&3\\0&1\end{bmatrix} times **u**.

Solve for **u** = $(y,z)$ by back substitution, $z$, before $y$:

Solve $dz/dt = z$ from $z(0) = -2$. Then solve $dy/dt = 4y + 3z$ from $y(0) = 5$.

The solution with be a combination of $e^{4t}$ and $e^t$. The $\lambda$'s are $4$ and $1$.

---

Solution Given:

$z(t) = 2e^t$ solves $dx/dt = x$ with $z(0) = 2$. Then $dy/dt = 4y-6e^t$ with $y(0) = 5$ gives $y(t) = 3e^4t + 2e^t$.

---

I understand how he solves this using linear algebra (I have yet to study differential equations). Furthermore the solving of z(t) makes sense to me as well. I do not understand how, given the context of no mention of differential equations prior, one should solve this question given the question itself.

I originally thought that you could just do something like:

$$\int(dy) = \int(4y - 6e^t)dt $$

$$y(t) = 4yt - 6e^t + c$$

But $y(0)$ leaves no $y$ for me to solve for.

Comment: The problem statement has a derivative in it and expands into two differential equations. I don't see how to avoid using knowledge of diff eq's to solve.

Comment: Okay, I was just wondering if there was a way to do this given the context of linear algebra. Thank you - will look into it.